# How to stop to open new content in angular ngx-input-file

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular6, angular4-forms

I am using angular ngx-input-file for drag and upload images. But in this module, If i drag and drop the image in a placeholder, it will automatically open the new placeholder to drag and drop.

I don't want to open the new placeholder. If i drag and drop the image, it should upload the image and could not open the new content. How can I hide or how can i remove that functionality. Please help me to do this.

Please look at the below example,

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-input-file?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean that when you drag an image to the first placeholder, you don't want the second placeholder to appear?

If so, set fileLimit to 1. That should do it.

```
<input-file inputId="input-file" fileAccept="image/*" fileLimit="1" placeholder="Pictures"></input-file>
```

Also in your `app-component.ts`, you will see a default config. Set the limit their to 1 if you want that to be your stand behaviour.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mattijs. Can you  please tell me how can I do this? , If file lime is not 1, for example if i drag and upload 5 images, how can I drag and reorder? I want to change the order. Please help me in this.

Comment: Reordering is not possible, it seems. You can only hover over an image that was uploaded and delete it to free up the placeholder. You either ask the plugin develop if he wants to add this feature or try adding it your self by doing a Fork of the repo and offer him a pull request.

Comment: If i drop image, one delete button will come, I want one more button on same content. one image with 2 buttons, That option also is not there. Is this possible to add one more button